# How to get L.polygon border, excluding inner points

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am working with `Leaflet.js` library. I have an array of geographical points, described by latitude and longitude and a polygon, based on this points. How can i remove inner points of polygon and draw only it's outer border?

Array of points

```
[[53, 31], [51.4, 31.2], [51.3, 32] ... etc.] //it's length ~ 500 points.
```

Initializing map

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(mymap);
```

Setting polygon

```
L.polygon(points, {color: 'red'}).addTo(mymap);
```

This is what i have right now. Here is all of 500 points is shown.
[image]

Result i am expecting. Here all internal points are removed, showing the covered area.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a convex hull algorithm: it would provide you with the "envelope" of your Points.

You can use e.g. Turfjs: https://turfjs.org/docs/#convex

But note that it requires working with data converted to GeoJSON objects.

You can also have a look at how Leaflet.markercluster plugin has implemented it.